# Capistrano deploying to different servers with different authentication methods

Tags: amazon-ec2, capistrano

I need to deploy to 2 different server and these 2 servers have different authentication methods (one is my university's server and the other is an amazon web server AWS)

I already have running capistrano for my university's server, but I don't know how to add the deployment to AWS since for this one I need to add ssh options for example to user the .pem file, like this:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "test.pem")] 
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

I have browsed starckoverflow and no post mention about how to deal with different authentication methods [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661868/using-capistrano-to-deploy-a-rails-application-to-multiple-web-servers)

I [found a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154161/capistrano-and-several-ssh-keys) that talks about 2 different keys, but this one refers to a server and a git, both usings different pem files. This is not the case.

I got to [this tutorial](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html), but couldn't find what I need.

I don't know if this is relevant for what I am asking: I am working on a rails app with ruby 1.9.2p290 and rails 3.0.10 and I am using an svn repository

Please any help os welcome. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is best handled through ssh-configs rather than Capistrano directly. It's easier, anyway. The trick is aluded to in [Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7155108/388165) on Stackoverflow. You'd build your `~/.ssh/config` file to supply the needed parameters for the hosts you're looking for. Happily, this config file can accept wildcards which makes it easier to distinguish between AWS and Univ machines.

```
Host *.univ.edu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host [aws things]
    IdentityFIle ~/.ssh/aws.pem
    ForwardAgent Yes
```

The `IdentityFile` directive tells SSH which SSH key to use, which is how you tell it to select the right one depending on where you're going. The `ForwardAgent` is equivalent to the Capistrano directive you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I do this exact thing using **multistage** from the [capistrano-ext](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/7/23/capistrano-multistage) extension.

```
 gem install capistrano-ext
```

I have a few different *stages* created in `config/deploy/` each with their own capistrano settings.

```
lunix@madeira]  (master) -> cat config/deploy/foo.rb 

set :user,   'ubuntu'
ssh_options[:keys] = File.expand_path('~/.ssh/awsfoo.pem')

server 'foo-01.example.com', :foo
```

.

```
lunix@madeira]  (master) -> cat config/deploy/bar.rb 

set :user,   'aussielunix'
ssh_options[:keys] = File.expand_path('~/.ssh/awsbar.pem')

server 'bar-01.example.org', :bar
```

Now it is a matter of just preceding the task with what *stage* you want to run the task against.

```
cap foo deploy
cap bar deploy
```